# Сравнение значения ячеек гугл таблицы с помощью gspread

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

Ребята, небольшой вопрос по gspread, как мне сравнивать значения ячеек? Вот я получил значения

```
        demping = []

        #получение значений ячейки
    
        #Имя товара
        named_list = sheet_instance.get('A1:A15')
    
        #Эталонная цена товара РРЦ
        sheet_instance_MTI = sheet_instance.get('B1:B15')
    
        #Цена товара на сайте партнера
        sheet_instance_our_company = sheet_instance.get('D1:D15')
```

И теперь я попытался в цикле сравнить значения ячеек, и несоответствиями заполнить список `demping`

```
#цикл сравнения значений ячейки 
        
        #Если цена на сайте партнера меньше чем эталонная цена товара, заносим первую цену в список
        for i in range(1, 15):

         if sheet_instance_MTI(f"B{i}") < sheet_instance_our_company(f'D{i}'):

            #if sheet_instance_MTI(i) < sheet_instance_our_company(i): так тоже не работает
    
            demping.append(named_list(f'A{i}'))
            print(demping)
```

Но ничего не получилось, как я могу это реализовать, подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Окей, я разобрался в чем проблема, дело в том что я мог брать по одной ячейки, а не сравнивать диапазон ячеек, используя вот такой цикл все получилось

```
 for i in range(3,15):
        
         if sheet_instance.acell(f'B{i}').value > sheet_instance.acell(f'D{i}').value:
            print(sheet_instance.get(f'A{i}'))
            #if sheet_instance_MTI(i) < sheet_instance_our_company(i): так тоже не работает

            demping.append(sheet_instance.get(f'A{i}'))
        print(demping)
```